# Removing Grub2 and reverting back to windows 8 boot loader

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, windows-8, bootloader

I'm new to stack exchange and Ubuntu. 
This question might be repeated but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have Ubuntu installed on my external hdd. I could boot it fine without any issues.

After a few days due to some reason I couldn't boot Ubuntu since it wasn't showing up when I selected boot from external device so I used boot repair which installed grub.

I have windows 8 preinstalled on my laptop. 
Now the problem is I have to connect my external hdd every time I want to load windows8.
I want to remove grub now and switch to default windows boot without deleting Ubuntu.
I've tried bootsect /nt60 sys 
Bootsect /nt60 all

Both haven't done the job for 
me.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Bootsect is for MBR drives, since you have Windows 8 I would assume you are using UEFI. Before doing a repair you should find out how many UEFI partitions you have and where the Ubuntu one is currently stored or you might end up unable to boot Ubuntu or Windows.

Install Windows 8 Bootloader ON UEFI System:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s S: /f UEFI
```

Additional Readings:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824874.aspx

Comment: ps: dism is a very handy tool for backing up your UEFI partition as a .wim so you can easily restore screw ups.

Comment: make sure to adjust S: to the appropriate drive letter

Comment: I'm kinda new to these terminologies like UEFI and MBR. I have no idea what dism is or how it works. Do u have any usefull links that could help me learn stuff? I'd rather do some research before screwing my system up.

Comment: Also would bcdboot overwrite grub? Because that's what I want.